# Why does Tor use only one hop instead of three hops to connect to a directory server?

Tags: bootstrapping, directory, tunneldirconns, one-hop

The [Tor manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en) says:

> **TunnelDirConns 0|1**
>
> If non-zero, when a directory server we contact supports it, we will build a one-hop circuit and make an encrypted connection via its ORPort. (Default: 1)

Why only one hop? Why not a regular three hop circuit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can Tor use a one hop circuit to a directory server during initial bootstrap?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/287/how-can-tor-use-a-one-hop-circuit-to-a-directory-server-during-initial-bootstrap)

Comment: @PeterPalfrader These questions are about the same setting in Tor, and probably should have been asked as one, but I don't know if they're sufficiently similar to call a duplicate. They are fundamentally different questions when it comes down to it.

Comment: Dear all, why I cannot find "TunnelDirConns 0|1" in https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en? is the feature already removed?

Answer (score 2):

No reason to be secret that you're getting the directory.

The only thing this tells people looking at you is that you just turned on Tor. But they already knew that because... You just turned on Tor

Comment: If there is no reason to hide the connection to the directory, why TunnelDirConns is set to 1 by default?

Comment: @adrelanos Look at the description again; TunnelDirConns is set to 1 which means it will build a one-hop circuit (aka nothing to hide).

Comment: TunnelDirConns 0: Tor client -> directory server.

Comment: TunnelDirConns 1: Tor client -> one relay -> directory server.

Comment: If there is nothing to hide, why "TunnelDirConns 0" isn't the default? Why not connect to a directory server? Why is "TunnelDirConns 1" the default, why is there one relay in between the Tor client and the directory server? (I am not advocating any change of default, just want to understand the ideas behind it.)